# From flat list of entities to list of groups

Tags: c#, linq

I have an entity like this:

```
class MyEntity {
     public int Id{ get; set; }
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public EventData Data { get; set; }
     // other stuff...
}
```

where EventData is something like:

```
class EventData {
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TerminationDate { get; set; }
    // other stuff...
}
```

when "GroupId" is null or empty the entity is not part of a group.
Entities with the same "GroupId" are part of the same group.

What i need to achieve is a list of groups in which the key is a complex type (anonymous or not... i don't know) and the corresponding value is the list of entities.

Each group key must be a complex type because i will use it to sort the groups according to one of its
properties.

For example the key will be:

```
class MyKey {
    public bool IsGroup { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Indeed, if "IsGroup" is false (and GroupId is null), the corresponding value will be a list containing only one entity.

The object should be something like:

```
List<IGrouping<Mykey, List<MyEntity>> ...
```

Thank you for your help. I hope it's clear enough :)

**INPUT EXAMPLE**

```
List<MyEntity> entities = new List<MyEntity>() 
{
    new MyEntity {
        Id = 1,
        Data = new EventData {
            GroupId = null
        }
    },
    new MyEntity {
        Id = 2,
        Data = new EventData {
            GroupId = null
        }
    },
    new MyEntity {
        Id = 3,
        Data = new EventData {
            GroupId = "1"
        }
    },
    new MyEntity {
        Id = 4,
        Data = new EventData {
            GroupId = "1"
        }
    }
}
```

Starting from this simplyfied input example, the output should be a list with 3 objects:

1. Key with IsGroup=false and GroupId=null. The value is a list containing only
   the entity with id=1.
2. Key with IsGroup=false and GroupId=null. The value is a list containing only
   the entity with id=2.
3. Key with IsGroup=true and GroupId="1". The value is a list containing the 
   entities with id=3 and id=4.

Comment: Please, share example input and output. Also, this declaration `public EventData { get; set; }` isn't valid

Comment: Done, i did my best! :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of the `MyKey` class so that we can use it to `GroupBy` the list of entities (without doing this, the default "reference-equals" equality will be used and we'll get no matches when `GroupBy` compares two keys for equality).

Given the requirements that two groups are only equal if `IsGroup` is `true`, they have the same `GroupId`, and the same `CreationDate`, we can implement `Equals` like:

```
class MyKey : IEquatable<MyKey>
{
    public bool IsGroup { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MyKey other)
    {
        // Note that we use 'other.IsGroup' to ensure that non-groups are not 
        // grouped together. Otherwise we would use 'other.IsGroup == IsGroup'.
        return other != null &&
               other.IsGroup &&
               other.GroupId == GroupId &&
               other.CreationDate == CreationDate;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as MyKey);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return IsGroup.GetHashCode() * 17 + 
               (GroupId?.GetHashCode() ?? 1) * 17 +
               CreationDate.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

With that done, we can now use the `MyKey` class to group the list of entities:

```
List<IGrouping<MyKey, MyEntity>> groups = entities.GroupBy(e =>
    new MyKey
    {
        CreationDate = e.Data?.CreationDate ?? DateTime.MinValue,
        GroupId = e.Data?.GroupId,
        IsGroup = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data?.GroupId)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: So by doing this, according to my input example i get 3 groups?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, since it's easy enough to test. Are you saying that you're not getting 3 groups? What is the difference in the output you're getting, compared to the output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you don't need this redundant `IsGroup` property. The grouping key is either `Entity.Id` when `EventData.GroupId` is null, or else `EventData.GroupId`:

```cs
var grouped = entities.GroupBy(e => new
{
    EntityKey = e.Data.GroupId == null ? e.Id : 0,
    DataKey = e.Data.GroupId
});
```

This creates three groups having the keys...

```
EntityKey   DataKey
1           null
2           null
0           1
```

...and having items `[entity 1]`, `[entity 2]`, and `[entity3, entity4]`, respectively